# how to modify a make file used by mingw so that the linker input is a file with objects?

Tags: makefile, mingw

I use Visual Studio with VisualGDB and i have around 2000 .c files
The visualgdb offers some template make files. The issue is that if there are too many files i get this windows 10 limitation error(command is too long)

```
 process_begin: CreateProcess(C:\SysGCC\mingw32\bin\g++.exe, C:/SysGCC/mingw32/bin/g++.exe -o Debug/WindowsProject2.exe -Wl,-gc-sections -Wl,--start-group Debug/Source.o Debug/thisIsAveryLongFilenameYesSir0.o Debug/thisIsAveryLongFilenameYesSir1.o Debug/thisIsAveryLongFilenameYesSir10.o Debug/thisIsAveryLongFilenameYesSir100.o Debug/thisIsAveryLongFilenameYesSir998.o 
 ....many files ...
 Debug/thisIsAveryLongFilenameYesSir999.o    -Wl,--end-group
1>  Makefile:137: recipe for target 'Debug/WindowsProject2.exe' failed
1>  -------------------------------------------------------------
1>  Command exited with code 2
1>  Executable: cmd.exe
1>  Arguments: /c "C:\SysGCC\mingw32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" -j8 CONFIG=Debug
1>  Directory: C:\Users\timo\Desktop\Study\Embedded\STM32\VisualGDB\WindowsProject2\WindowsProject2
1>VisualGDB : error : Command-line action failed
```

I found the make commands from the make file templae generated by visualGDB

```
ifeq ($(TARGETTYPE),SHARED)
$(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME): $(all_objs) $(EXTERNAL_LIBS)
    $(LD) -shared -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(START_GROUP) $(all_objs) $(LIBRARY_LDFLAGS) $(END_GROUP)
endif
```

And the support sent me 2 variants who doesnt work:

1.

```
ifeq ($(TARGETTYPE),APP)
$(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME): $(all_objs) $(EXTERNAL_LIBS)
 @echo $(all_objs) > $@.in
 $(LD) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(START_GROUP) @$@.in $(LIBRARY_LDFLAGS) $(END_GROUP)
endif
```

2.

```
ifeq ($(TARGETTYPE),APP)
$(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME): $(all_objs) $(EXTERNAL_LIBS)
<TAB>@echo -g > $@.in
<TAB>$(foreach obj,$(all_objs),cmd /c “echo $(obj) >> $@.in”)
<TAB> $(LD) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(START_GROUP) @$@.in $(LIBRARY_LDFLAGS) $(END_GROUP)
endif
```

Variant 1  there is on 17_01_Dev.exe.in which contains the list of objects like

Debug/file2.o Debug/file1.o …

But its limited to aprox 8190 characters and then it cuts out all the other objects

Please help :(

Answer (score 1):

Finnaly it works with this !

```
ifeq ($(TARGETTYPE),APP)
$(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME): $(all_objs) $(EXTERNAL_LIBS)
    $(file >$@.in,$^)
    $(LD) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(START_GROUP) @$@.in $(LIBRARY_LDFLAGS) $(END_GROUP)
endif
```